# ASP.NET MVC Application Timeout Not Working

Tags: asp.net-mvc, session, web-config, timeout, session-state

In my Web.config file, I have been trying to set the session timeout. I used the following code:

```
<configuration>
   <system.web>
      <sessionState timeout="1"></sessionState>
   </system.web>
</configuration>
```

When I ran the app, the timeout was still set to the default 20 minutes. Trying to figure out why the settings are not applying. Please help! Thanks!

Answer (score 5):

Don't be confused between ASP.NET session timeout (which is what you set) and [Forms Authentication](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ff647070.aspx) cookie timeout which is something entirely different and controlled by the `<forms>` tag:

```
<authentication mode="Forms">
  <forms
    loginUrl="/login"
    timeout="1" />
</authentication>
```

ASP.NET session uses cookies to track users (it has nothing to do with authentication) and associate their unique id with a hashtable stored on the server. Forms authentication on the other hand is a means of tracking authenticated users in ASP.NET. It uses cookies but it is a different cookie than the ASP.NET session.

Comment: I already have this kind of code implemented, what I am working on is after about 20 min, all the buttons on the page stop working and the app is essentially broken until you refresh the page. So I want to increase the timeout.

Comment: How are those buttons implemented? Are they relying on forms authentication or ASP.NET session?

Comment: They have data-binds on them and the click events are bound to functions on JavaScript view model object.

Comment: So you are using AJAX? And you are invoking controller actions which require authentication? How are those actions implemented? Do they use ASP.NET session? I guess that once the forms authentication timeout expires they redirect to the LogOn page and break your AJAX calls. Read the following article for possible ways of detecting this condition: http://haacked.com/archive/2011/10/04/prevent-forms-authentication-login-page-redirect-when-you-donrsquot-want.aspx